# Using Selenium and Beautiful Soup with regards to finding elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to web scraping and data science in general.
According to various sources, beautifulsoup is faster than selenium for web scraping. 
I am writing some code that crawls through social media comments. I'm using Selenium to automate clicking the button that retrieves older comments and to grab the text from the comments using

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath()
```

I know beautifulsoup does not have a feature that allows me to directly input the xpath to find an element.

In this case, should I wean off relying on using xpath and try to get more comfortable with using selectors that can be used by beautiful soup instead?

My code right now feels super clunky and takes a few minutes, although I'm only processing around 120 comments.

Sorry if this question has been asked before; I wasn't able to find it on the site. Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful soup can use xpath or css. It's probably a good idea to avoid BS-specific selector syntax if you plan on switching between other libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your code works well. Not sure what you are looking for so hard to say it but yes it's common faster to use requests and beautifulsoup

Here is good instruction
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-web-data-using-requests-and-beautiful-soup-with-python-3

You will love css selector from soup

```
for cell in soup.select('table#foobar td.empformbody'):
    # your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy is a python library that is also designed for web scraping. It has more options than soup, one of which includes directly using xpaths to scrape information. You might want to look into using it, I find it easier to use than soup.